# Apache Listen configuration

Tags: apache, http, configuration

What is the difference between the following configurations

```
Listen *:80 //anything at port 80
Listen 192.168.0.34:80 //from an internal ip on port 80
Listen 173.194.35.23:80 //from an external ip on port 80
```

Which of them is the best configuration (if there is any difference between them). I want my server to be accessed from internet not just from a LAN.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I always use `*:80`.

You can only listen on IPs that are actually bound to the network cards of your server but it's poor practice to have a server that straddle internal and external networks, IMHO, so I wouldn't define internal and external addresses.

The only time I think it is necessary to be specific about what IP address you listen on is if you have particular IP based virtual hosting.

Answer (score 4):

One Apache server can have multiple IPs for multiple domains.

```
Listen *:80 --> Apache listens no matter what ip request the web browser
Listen 192.168.0.34:80 ---> Apache listens only if web browser requests http://192.168.0.34 . 192.x.x.x use to be internal IPs
Listen 173.194.35.23:80 ---- Apache listens only if web browser requests http://Listen 173.194.35.23
```

listen *:80 is enough if you only have a site domain. The other configurations are to serve multiple sites/domains into one apache server.

Some documentation examples http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html