# Why does 127.0.0.1:80 not work in apache virtualhost?

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, localhost, virtualhost

I can work around this, but I'd like to understand better what's going on.

Using Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu, in a local development environment, a virtual host with *:80 as the address works, but 127.0.0.1:80 doesn't.  Neither does localhost:80.  I only have one .conf file with virtual hosts in it besides the main appache2.conf file.  Here's what's in that separate vhosts file:

> <VirtualHost  CCNM-378B:80  # **Does not work**. (CCNM-378B is what
> 'hostname' from the command line says)
>
> <VirtualHost  127.0.0.1:80  # **Does not work**.
>
> <VirtualHost  localhost:80  # **Does not work**.
>
> <VirtualHost  *:80  # **WORKS**
>
> ServerName localhost

In etc/hosts I have:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost

**access.log is empty**, but other_vhosts_access.log says:

> 127.0.0.1:80 ::1 - - [25/Mar/2022:10:20:29 -0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 487 "http://localhost/ideatree/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
> NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/99.0.4844.83 Safari/537.36"

error.log (at level 'debug') says:

> [core:info] [pid 4150:tid 140212272101120] [client ::1:58080] AH00128:
> File does not exist: /var/www/html/ideatree/

...with DEBUG=True set in Django settings (though all this is ostensibly happening well before Django is involved.)

In apache2.conf I have:

> ServerName 127.0.0.1
>
> #ServerName localhost

But neither of these seem to make a difference.

The app that Apache is serving is a Django app.

The [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) say the following about vhost name resolution, but it doesn't explain why this is happening since the base apache2.conf defines '127.0.0.1' as ServerName but that isn't recognized in the VirtualHost.

> If a VirtualHost doesn't specify a ServerName, a server name will be
> inherited from the base server configuration.

Comment: the access log entry you posted is not the line that shows the access to your django app. Please post the first lines in access.log after you make the request to your app. What is exactly the error message in Apache error.log (with django settings debug=True!) in the cases where you say "it does not work".

Comment: I've edited the question to include that info.

Comment: You get the error because favicon.ico is not found which your browser tries to download because it is part of the html file that is before most certainly served by your django app. "most certainly" because you do not provide any files to be able to judge what is really going on.

Comment: When the VirtualHost is set to listen to *:80 both favicon.ico as well as the entire application are found.  That being said, as an experiment, I put a 'Listen 127.0.0:80 statement at the top of the VirtualHost config, and got the following when starting Apache:  "(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80  no listening sockets available, shutting down"  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177564/apache-listen-configuration)  on SO is interesting, as well as [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html).